# Addition in php from more than one row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to make a little game, where I need to add some point given for how a drink looks and taste.

There will be 7 people giving points, so in php i need to create a table for each date and only show 1 name for each of the players, but I need the points to be added for every row with the same name:

Here is what I have so far.

```
  <?php     

    $pdo = Logbase::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT start FROM grade';      
    $q = $pdo->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);?> 
<?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
 <table class="blueTable" align="center">

<thead>

<tr>
<th> <?php echo $r['start'] ?></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<tbody>
<?php     

    $pdo = Logbase::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM grade group by start, name';      
    $q = $pdo->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  ?> 
 <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>                 
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $r['name'] ?></td>
<td> <?php echo $r['drinks_fla'] + $r['drinks_view']  + $r['food'] + 
 $r['sam'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

In my result I can see 1 name for each player, but only 1 rows has been added (the first), so I quess I need a loop or something in my mysql?

Dennis --------10 point
Michael--------6 point

I want to see 
Dennis 24 point
Michale 12 points

### id---start--- name-----drinks_fla---drinks_view

1---31.07-2017---dennis---5---5 
1---31.07-2017---dennis---4---3
1---31.07-2017---dennis---5---2
2---31.07-2017---Michale---5---1
2---31.07-2017---Michael---2---4

Comment: you already loop over the results with `<?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>`. the reason you are seeing just one is because you only fetch rows with distinct `start` values in your SQL (`'SELECT DISTINCT start FROM grade'`). my guess is that you are after `DISTINCT name`

Comment: that is only to show the date 1 time, I close it be4 I try to add all the points

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM grade group by start, name';
```

You have grouped your Results from MySQL, so only one Row will be called for the Properties of the Group.

Try "sum()" to get sum of the selected Columns you want:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name as name,sum(sum(drinks_fla),sum(drinks_view)) as sum FROM grade group by start, name';
```

MySQL will call all Rows, ordered by the first Property. All Rows with the same first Property are sorted with the second one.

Example:

```
id---start--- name-----drinks_fla---drinks_view

1---31.07-2017---dennis---5---5
1---31.07-2017---dennis---4---3
1---31.07-2017---dennis---5---2
2---31.07-2017---Michale---5---1
2---31.07-2017---Michael---2---4

Result:
name----sum
dennis----24
Michale----6
Michael----6
```

Comment: then I see the user 3 times

Comment: Ahh, now i've seen that you want to sum the Rows...use "sum(<column>). With Group By mysql-result will call the sum of the selected rows.

Comment: You're not going to know which 'start' is which

Comment: start is my date. but I am no sure what you mean?